# Is it possible to pull fields across multiple objects using Remote Objects?

Tags: javascript-remoting, remote-objects

Perhaps I am missing something, but I cannot seem to find an example showing where someone has pulled data via Remote Objects across several custom objects. In this particular use case, I am attempting to pull fields from two different objects joined by way of a junction object in a many-to-many relationship. Is this one of the limitations of Remote Objects or just not very well-documented? Am I required to use Javascript Remoting in this instance?

Comment: What are you querying on, the junction object or the two related objects and how are you trying to structure the query? Posting code always makes a post easier to respond to. Examples of remote object queries aren't plentiful and performing complex queries wasn't what it was intended for. I'd expect complex queries would best be done in a controller. You could still use js remoting to speed up your page.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Remoting may be better at performing this. It is made for more complex requests. I would look there if you are avoiding apex.

Or just use apex as the first comment suggests.